# How do I find the equation of a polynomial with real cofficients having $2$ and $5-2i$ as zeroes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the equation of a polynomial with real coefficients having $2$ and $5-2i$ as zeroes?

Do I set the two equal to zero to help me find the equation? Would anyone be able to show the work?

Answer (score 0):

If it has real coefficients and
$a+bi$ as a root
then it also has
$a-bi$ as a root.

So a factor is
$(x-(a+bi))(x-(a-bi))
=x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2
$.

So if roots are
$2$ and $5-2i$
the polynomial is
$(x-2)(x^2-10x+29)
=x^3 - 12 x^2 + 49 x - 58
$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $5+2i$ is also a root. Thus your polynomial is: $P(x)=(x-2)(x-5+2i)(x-5-2i)=(x-2)(x^2-10x+29)$

Answer (score 0):

You have roots $x = 2$ and $x = 5 - 2i$.  Now work backwards.
\begin{align*}
x & = 2 & x & = 5 - 2i\\
x - 2 & = 0 & x - 5 & =  2i\\
 & & (x - 5)^2 & = (2i)^2\\
 & & x^2 - 10x + 25 & = -4\\
 & & x^2 - 10x + 29 & = 0
\end{align*}
One solution is 
\begin{align*}
(x - 2)(x^2 - 10x + 29) & = x(x^2 - 10x + 29) - 2(x^2 - 10x + 29)\\
                        & = x^3 - 10x^2 + 29x - 2x^2 + 20x - 58\\
                        & = x^3 - 12x^2 + 49x - 58
\end{align*}